# Optimizing Searchkick in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using ES and Searchkick gem to handle searches in my Rails app. I'm currently doing:

```
class Paper < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  belongs_to :user
  before_destroy :delete_dependant_papers

  searchkick word_start: [:realname]
end
```

This works great but it is unnecessarily indexing every column. I want it to index only the "realname" column.

I then came across `search_data` in the [Searchkick GitHub](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) page. This allows me to index only certain columns:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base  
def search_data
    as_json only: [:name, :active]
    # or equivalently
    {
      name: name,
      active: active
    }
  end
end
```

How would I combine both of these? So that only 1 column is indexed with realname and word_start?

Comment: So, you want to index `realname` only, nothing else right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`search_data` method will let you index `realname`, and `word_start` will let you partially match your data. So your model need to look like this:

```
class Paper < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  belongs_to :user
  before_destroy :delete_dependant_papers

  searchkick word_start: [:realname]

  def search_data
    as_json only: [:realname]
  end
end
```

You need to call `Paper.reindex` in your console after changing `search_data` method.